# In TABLE: Customize Checkboxes And Radio Buttons With CSS3

Tags: button, checkbox, html-table, radio-button, label

I styled my radiobuttons using this tutorial: 
[a link](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/)
It works perfect without a tablelayout! But..

I have a fix tablelayout and I can not change anything on this layout (the layout comes from an old generator). The label and the inputtype (radiobutton) are in separate tables.

Have anyone a idea? How can I style the radiobutton inside the table?

My jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ETp5w/

The HTML

```
<!-- Tablelayout .. is not working!!! -->   
<table class="" width="100.0%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <colgroup>
            <col width="100.0%">
          </colgroup>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="">

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1" class="abc" id="radiobutton1">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <label for="radiobutton1"><span class="spantext">answer1<br></span></label>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td class="next">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2" class="abc" id="radiobutton2">
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <label for="radiobutton2"><span class="spantext">answer2<br></span></label>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td class="next">
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>


<!-- Same code without tables. Works! -->   

    <input id="answer3" type="radio" name="answer" value="3"></td>
    <label for="answer3">answer3</label>

    <input id="answer4" type="radio" name="answer" value="4">
    <label for="answer4">answer4</label>
```

The CSS

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    font-size: 13px;
    width: 100%;
}

label:checked::before {
    background-color: yellow;
}

input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}

label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;

    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;

    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
}

label:hover::before {
    background-color: red;
}


input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
    background-color: red;
}

.radio label:before {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```